# Identify and intercept function call

Tags: windows, hook, reverse-engineering, disassembly, ida

I'm developing a launcher for a game.
Want to intercept game's call for a function that prints text.

I don't know whether the code that contains this function is dynamically linked or statically. So I dont even know the function name.

I did intercepted some windows-api calls of this game through microsoft Detours, Ninject and some others.

But this one is not in import table either.

What should I do to catch this function call? What profiler should be used? IDA? How this could be done?

---

**EDIT:**

Finally found function address. Thanks, Skino!

Tried to hook it with Detours, injected dll. Injected DllMain:

```
typedef int (WINAPI *PrintTextType)(char *, int, float , int);

static PrintTextType PrintText_Origin = NULL;

int WINAPI PrintText_Hooked(char * a, int b, float c, int d)
{
    return PrintText_Origin(a, b, c , d);
}

HMODULE game_dll_base;
/* game_dll_base initialization goes here */

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    if(fdwReason==DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
        DisableThreadLibraryCalls(hinstDLL);
        DetourTransactionBegin();
        DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
        PrintText_Origin = (PrintTextType)((DWORD)game_dll_base + 0x6049B0);
        DetourAttach((PVOID *)&PrintText_Origin , PrintText_Hooked);
        DetourTransactionCommit();
    }
}
```

It hooks as expected. Parameter `a` has text that should be displayed. But when calling original function `return PrintText_Origin (a, b, c , d);` application crashes(http://i46.tinypic.com/ohabm.png, http://i46.tinypic.com/dfeh4.png)

***Original function disassembly:***

http://pastebin.com/1Ydg7NED

***After Detours:***

<s>http://pastebin.com/eM3L8EJh</s>

**EDIT2:**

***After Detours:***

http://pastebin.com/GuJXtyad

`PrintText_Hooked` disassembly http://pastebin.com/FPRMK5qt **w3_loader.dll** is the injected dll

Im bad at ASM, please tell what can be wrong ?

Comment: Have you actually located this function in the game code? Or do you need guidance on how to find it so you can intercept it?

Comment: Actually I have no idea how to find this function. And even dont know where to go. I just know this is possible ;)

Comment: Then it looks like you're gonna have to dive into a debugger or a disassembler. We can't exactly give you a tutorial on that in this comment box :) (Out of curiosity, what game is this?)

Comment: Have disassembled main DLL. disassembly has tons of functions. How to find exactly one what Iam looking for? What strategy should I use? (game is wc3 from blizzard)

Comment: As I said, that question is too broad to be answered here - look into some reverse engineering tutorials. A possible start would be to look for hardcoded strings, printf format specifiers or C++ io streams.

Comment: @Didar_Uranov so far so good, `WINAPI` appears correct, can you also tell IDA to refresh the assembly from `base+6049B0` until `base+6049B7` *after the detour* (IIRC the shortcut is 'i' while the each line between the two addresses is selected, or first hit 'd' then 'i'), then pastebin the updated disassembly for "after detours" as well as the disassembly for the location where that very first `jmp` is sending you after you refresh the disassembly, e.g. `unk_XXXXXX` (use 'i' over there as well, if needed.)

Comment: @Didar_Uranov sorry that would be 'c', not 'i'.

Comment: @Didar_Uranov the new snippet (`xx1A70`) looks good too, but it's calling a *second* place inside your dll (`xxE554`). After the detours keep on following all `call`s in the detour codepath until you hit `sub_6F6049B7` again. Also, what is the address of `PrintText_Origin`, `xx1A70` or `xxE554` or neither? (`xx....` is the base of your injected DLL.)

Comment: PrintText_Origin is xxE554 after detours. Can we contact via skype or mail ? I'll give the sources would be much easier for you to help me :)

Answer (score 1):

At this stage it sounds like you don't have a notion of what library function you're trying to hook, and you've stated it's not (obviously at least) an imported external function in the import table which probably means that the function responsible for generating the text is likely located inside the .text of the application you are disassembling directly or loaded dynamically, the text generation (especially in a game) is likely a part of the application.

In my experience, this simplest way to find code that is difficult to trace such as this is by stopping the application shortly during or before/after text is displayed and using IDA's fabulous call-graph functionality to establish what is responsible for writing it out (use watches and breakpoints liberally!)

Look carefully to calls to [CreateRemoteThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682437%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or any other commonly used dynamic loading mechanism if you have reason to believe this functionality might be provided by an exported function that isn't showing up in the import table.

I strongly advice against it but for the sake of completeness, you could also hook NtSetInformationThread in the [system service dispatch table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). here's a good dump of the table for different Windows versions [here](http://j00ru.vexillium.org/ntapi/). If you want to get the index in the table yourself you can just disassemble the NtSetInformationThread export from ntdll.dll.

Answer (score 1):

> Want to intercept game's call for a function that prints text.

You can **use a debugger for the investigative phase**. Either IDA, or even Visual Studio (in combination with e.g. HxD), should do. It should be relatively easy to identify the function using the steps below:

1. Identify a particular fragment of text whose printing you want to trace (e.g. `Hello World!`)
2. Break the game execution at any point *before* the game normally prints the fragment you identified above
3. Search for that fragment of text<sup>†</sup> (**look for either Unicode or ANSI**) in the game's memory. IDA will allow you to do that IIRC, as will the free [HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) (`Extras` > `Open RAM...`)
4. Once the address of the fragment has been identified, **set a break-on-access/read** data breakpoint so the debugger will give you control the moment the game attempts to *read* said fragment (while or immediately prior to displaying it)
5. Resume execution, wait for the data breakpoint to trigger
6. Inspect the stack trace and look for a suitable candidate for hooking
7. Step through from the moment the fragment is read from memory until it is printed if you want to explore additional potential hook points

<sup>†provided text is not kept compressed (or, for whatever reason, encrypted) until the very last moment</sup>

Once you are done with the investigative phase and you have identified where you'd like to inject your hook, you have **two options when writing your launcher**:

1. If, based on the above exercise, you were able to identify an export/import after all, then use any API hooking techniques
2. **EDIT** Use Microsoft Detours, making sure that you first correctly [**identify the calling convention** (cdecl, fastcall, stdcall)](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Calling_Convention_Examples#Microsoft_C_Compiler) of the function you are trying to detour, and use that calling convention for both the prototype of the original as well as for the implementation of the dummy. See [examples](https://github.com/RamseyK/hooktests/blob/master/dmdetour/dmdetour/dmdetour.cpp).
3. If not, you will have to

   - use the [Debugging API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679303.aspx) to programatically load the game
   - compute the hook address based on your investigative phase (either as a hard-coded offset from the module base, or by looking for the instruction bytes around the hook site<sup>‡</sup>)
   - set a breakpoint
   - resume the process
   - wait for the breakpoint to trigger, do whatever you have to do
   - resume execution, wait for the next trigger etc. **again, all done programatically by your launcher via the Debugging API**.

<sup>‡to be able to continue to work with eventual patch releases of the game</sup>

Comment: Have found function address. Tried to intercept with Microsoft Detours. Function is intercepted, replaced by dummy one, which calls original. But when calling original from dummy, application crashes. Found on google that when intercepting statically linked functions crashes can occur.

Can you please give more information about Debugging API. Have never used it before. Thanks